# Why use Transformations.switchMap?

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-architecture-components

Is there any advantage in using `Transformations.switchMap` like this

```java
MutableLiveData<Integer> userId = ...;
LiveData<User> user = Transformations.switchMap(userIdLiveData, id -> repository.getUserById(id));

void setUserId(int userId) {
    // why not query manually here?
    userIdLiveData.setValue(userId);
}
```

instead of just doing this:

```java
LiveData<User> user;

void setUserId(int userId) {
    user = repository.getUserById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `switchMap` "switches" source of data emitted by `user` LiveData object.

That means any existing observer of `user` will seamlessly obtain new user data after you change `userId`.

Your second "solution" replaces `user` LiveData itself so in addition to calling `setUserId` you will need to manually unregister observers from previous `user` LiveData and start observing the new one.